# Vue & TypeScript How to get the data property in render?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to use this in render when I use TypeScript. 
But it can't run:

> TS2339: Property 'options' does not exist on type
>   'ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods,
>   DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        onSwtich: Function
    }
}

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'footerTabs',
    data() {
        return {
            options: {
                on: {
                    click: el => this.onSwtich(el)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    render(h) {
        return h('swiper', {
            class: 'page-footer-tabs',
            attrs: {
                options: this.options  // TS2339: Property 'options' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Rec...'.
            }
        })
    },
    methods: {
        onSwtich(el): void {
            this.$emit('on-switch', el)
        }
    }
})
```

I have tried adding options to

> interface Vue {
>     options: object
>   }

It is still not working

Answer (score 1):

```
declare module 'vue/types/options' {
    interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
        options?: any
    }
}
```

It turns out that it needs to be declared like this.